# Proving density of irrationals only given $\pi$ irrational.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

As the title states, I am trying to prove the density of irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$, given only that $\pi$ is irrational, but not that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (basically I'm trying to not use the $x+\pi<r<y+\pi$ thing).

Here's what I've tried, I feel like the proof goes in a circle and doesn't feel legitimate:
Take $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x<y$.
If $x,y$ are both areas of circles with radius $r_x$ and $r_y$ respectively, then we must have
$$x<(r_x^2+r_y^2)\frac{\pi}{2}<y$$

Just wondering if this works at all.

Comment: **Hint :** Given that $\pi$ is irrational, prove that $\mathbb{Z} + \pi \mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Then prove that all the elements of $\mathbb{Z} + \pi \mathbb{Z}$ are irrational, and conclude.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: Wouldn't that only prove that the subset $\Bbb Z+\pi\Bbb Z$ of the set of irrationals $\Bbb Q^\complement$ is dense in $\Bbb R$? All elements of $\Bbb Z+\pi\Bbb Z$ are irrational but not the other way around.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas If $A \subset B \subset E$ and $A$ is dense in $E$, then $B$ is also dense in $E$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Not quite all elements of $\mathbb Z + \pi \mathbb Z$ are irrational (namely $\mathbb Z$).

Comment: @RobertIsrael You are right. I guess this can be easily fixed, though, by considering $(\mathbb{Z} + \pi \mathbb{Z} ) \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ instead of  $\mathbb{Z} + \pi \mathbb{Z}$.